# How do I intuitively make sense of "logically implies" in first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, intuition

I am reading Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic by Christopher Leary and Lars Kristiansen. In [Definition 1.9.1.](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Mathematical_Logic_and_Proof/Book%3A_Friendly_Introduction_to_Mathematical_Logic_(Leary_and_Kristiansen)/01%3A_Structures_and_Languages/1.10%3A_Logical_Implication), the authors define logically implies for two sets of $\mathcal{L}$-sentences $\Delta$ and  $\Gamma$ as follows:

We will say $\Delta$ logically implies $\Gamma$ and write $\Delta \models\Gamma$ if for each $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathfrak{U}$, if $\mathfrak{U}\models\Delta$ then $\mathfrak{U}\models \Gamma$.

The definition seems okay but it would really help me to understand as to why we are making such a definition and what the motivation really is behind this definition. I would like to know why we are demanding "for each model of $\Delta$" and not discussing truth in a particular model of $\Delta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write in particular:

> I would like to know why we are demanding "for each model of $\Delta$" and not discussing truth in a particular model of $\Delta$.

Often logic is introduced in the context of understanding some fixed structure such as the semiring of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ or (stretching the term "structure" a bit) the universe of set theory $V$. However, that's not something we have to do. The apparatus of first-order logic provides us with a broad collection of sentences which make sense (whether true or false) in *arbitrary* structures, and we care right at the outset about the general behavior of this apparatus. The definition of logical entailment reflects *this* level of generality. We may later consider modifications of the entailment relation *(although spoiler alert, none of them seem to have the same ultimate staying power)*, but to start with we should at least understand the "no-unnecessary-restrictions" situation.

It may help at this point to look at a particular mathematical claim in this context. Take for example the statement "If every element has order $2$, then every pair of elements commutes" in the context of group theory. The class of groups is **axiomatizable**: there is a set $\Delta_{grp}$ of first-order sentences such that the models of $\Delta_{grp}$ are exactly the groups. The fact that the statement above is true in every group amounts to the following logical entailment: $$\Delta_{grp}\models[\forall x(x*x=e)\rightarrow\forall x,y(x*y=y*x)].$$ Note that it's important that we range over *all* $\mathfrak{U}$s here; we're really trying to make a statement about arbitrary models of $\Delta_{grp}$ here.

Ultimately, I consider it a mistake to think about model theory as being oriented towards individual structures at all; model theory, in my opinion, is better thought of as the study of certain classes of, operations on, dividing lines amongst, and other things around **structures in general**.

Answer (score 2):

This is just the basic concept of logical implication: Something (call it $X$) logically implies something else (call it $Y$) if and only if $Y$ is true *whenever* $X$ is true.

Consider this. In our world, grass is green, and snow is white. Now, would you sat that grass being green logically implies that snow it white just because there is a world in which both statements are true?  Of course not. And of course grass being green does not logically imply snow being white: you can imagine a logically possible world where grass is green, but snow is not white.

In other words, $X$ does *not* imply $Y$ if there is some world where $X$ is true but $Y$ is false.  But that means that $X$ *does* imply $Y$ when there is no such world ... which is to say that in *every* world where $X$ is true, $Y$ will also be true.

Answer (score 1):

It might help if we think about when $\Delta \models \Gamma$ is false. Let's consider the contrapositive of the forall definition and call it (I).

$$ \textbf{(I)}\;\;\; \Delta \not\models \Gamma \;\;\text{iff}\;\; \text{there exists a model $M$ such that $M \models \Delta$ and $M \not\models \Gamma$ } $$

If we only looked at a single *not-fixed* model for $\models$, then the contrapositive would be as follows

$$  \textbf{(II)}\; \textbf{BAD} \;\;\; \Delta \not\models \Gamma \;\;\text{iff} \;\; \text{for all models $M$ where $M \models \Delta$, $M \not\models \Gamma$ holds} $$

The statement (II) is not compatible with the fact that implication only requires a single counterexample to be false.

If we look at a single fixed model $M$, then we're not talking about a relationship between $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ that always holds, but rather a relationship between them in $M$ alone.